# SSH connection between Ubuntu Server VM

Tags: linux, windows-10, ip, vmware, bridge-router

I'm trying to make SSH connection from my Windows 10 host to the Ubuntu Server VM.

At the beginning I built the VM from scratch on VMware and chose the Bridged Adapter configuration. It gave me IP of 192.168.1.138 on the current VM MAC.

When I tried to make SSH connection via Git Bash everything was working great.

I closed the VM and reopened it on the next day. Tried to connect via SSH and got an error (connection timed out).

After spending hours on the web I didn't find any good working solution.

What I did was:

```
sudo su
cd /etc/netplan
vim 00-installer-config.yaml
```

And configure my ens33 adapter as follows:

```
network:
  ethernets:
    ens33:
      dhcp4: false
      addresses:
        - 192.168.1.138/24
      routes:
        - to: default
          via: 192.168.1.1
  version: 2
```

I also tried to add the MAC of the Ubuntu with the IP to the vmnetdhcp.conf as a host and inside the VMnet1, VMnet8 also with changing the dhcp value to true, which also failed.

Another option was manually run `ip route` command but unfortunately I got an error with the gateway which is reasonable because the VM can't see my host GW.

Running `ip a` shows me this awkward info about the card:

```
1: lo ...
...
2: ens33: <BROADCAST, MULTICAST, UP, LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc fq_codel state UP group default qlen 1000 link/ether <MAC ADDRESS HERE> brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
altname enp2s1
inet 192.168.1.138/24 brd 192.168.1.255 scope global ens33
valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
inet6 fe80::20c:****:****:****/64 scope link
valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
```

What am I missing?

Comment: Did you enable and start the SSH service in Ubuntu?

Comment: @John Yes. Also played with firewall (this btw helped me fix the issue in my debian a year ago). Also played with the adapters themselves on the host (win10). On VMware i added NAT and SSHed threw it and it told me that public key wasnt correct, which may be cause of all the changes I made but on checking the debug of ssh I saw that my issue fails on the connection which is the first step.

Comment: Im afraid its a black hole that consists of VM settings and the gateway that im giving to it, and some fine tuning of some .conf files of the VMWare itself ... all this flow doesnt play right for me thus it fails. The ip route (for routing table) shows me default via 192.168.1.1 dev ens33 proto static 192.168.1.0/24 dev ens33 proto kernel scope link src 192.168.1.138  which looks fine. Its weird because its happened after the reboot of the VM.

Comment: I'm not sure why.  I have a Windows 11 Host, VMware Pro V17, and Ubuntu 22.04 guest. I set up SSH (installed SSH, and started the service).  Then Putty SSH in Windows 11 accesses the guest just fine. I am there now to test. Ubuntu NAT connection in VMware.